Why does each leg of my 240V outlet measure 125V to ground, but 217V across the hot wires?
When I measure from hot A to ground of my 240V receptacle, I see 125.3V on my multimeter. And 125.8V from hot B to ground.
But across hots A and B, I see 216.7V.  (There is no load when I'm measuring.)
I think I have single phase service, so shouldn't I be seeing something closer to 250V?  At first I thought I was missing something regarding RMS voltage, but I'm fairly certain my multimeter is only measuring RMS voltage to begin with.

Where is this--city and country?

@brhans If they were in Mexico, 127V/220V is nominal. See this electrical engineering explanation.

@user71659 I don't know what you're responding to, but I am an EE so I know how 3-phase power works (whether in Mexico or anywhere else).

@brhans We're responding to the deleted comment where you criticized us asking where the OP was.

@user71659 I think you're confused. My comment was directed so someone who had written about measuring to ground or something like that. Had nothing to do with asking where the OP is.

@brhans Nope. Jim Stewart asked his where is this question and you directly responded to him saying something like "what possible difference does that make."

@user71659 no - I wasn't responding to Jim at all. I was responding to a completely different (now also deleted) comment referring to the measurements. As far as I remember, my comment was directed to a user called "Traveller".

@brhans Wrong. It was to Jim Stewart and was terse, which is probably why, if not you, the mods deleted it.

@user71659 you probably only saw my comment after Traveler (?) deleted his, making it appear that's who I was referring to. I did not write anything to Jim or referring to his request for the OP's location.

@brhans Nope. I stand by what I said. It was directly addressed to Jim Stewart and said something very close to "What possible difference does the location make?"

I don't know what you think you saw. In any case, I'm done here. ¯\(ツ)/¯

TL;DR Your voltages are normal and should pose you no trouble.
There are two main voltage setups for residential use in the US:

120V/240V

This is the most common. The 120V neutral is the midpoint on a transformer between the two 240V ends. Really simple and easy to understand. But the actual voltages have crept up over the years, so most equipment has been actually rated for 125V or 250V, much as there are still people referring to 110V and 220V. Higher voltages are ever so slightly more efficient, so there has been a gradual shift over the last century from 100V to 110V to 115V to 120V.
Even though many people will refer to 240V (or 220V or 250V) as two phases, that is incorrect. This is all a single-phase system, with the two ends (240V) being the two legs and one leg with neutral = 120V.

120V/208V

This is when three-phase power is distributed with neutral being 120V to any of the three hot wires. This is common in large buildings, so it is often found in large apartment buildings, though technically even a small building could have power fed this way. The ratio of 120V to 208V is exactly the same as 125V to 217V.
The good news is that you really don't need to worry about this very much. Most large appliances (water heaters, clothes dryers, ovens, EV charging equipment) is designed to handle a range from 200V to 250V. This equipment won't heat/dry/cook/charge as fast at 208V as at 240V, though in your case 217V actually gets it pretty darn close to the old standard of 220V.

@Traveler you're free to make your own answer

Ah, so it ends up being ✓3*125V because I actually have three phases in my building, and not the single phase I wrongly assumed.  I kept trying to get the math to work with ✓2...

In this comment the OP has changed the facts as originally presented in the question. He should edit the original question so readers don't start pondering how he could get 217 V from a single phase system with legs each at 125 V.

An apartment building with 3-phase must have a lot of induction cooktops. Does the max power output of an induction surface unit vary with input voltage or do the electronics compensate? (We all know the max power output of the standard resistance  units is significantly less at 208 V or 217 V than at 240 V or 250 V.)

@JimStewart if it's fairly modern it might, or as people refit their kitchens.  As built it could easily have been all resistive

I think the missing context is that in a two phase system, the two "hot" wires are complete opposites of each other (when one is a maximum, the other is at minimum or 180 degrees apart), much like clock hands that are at 12 and 6.  In a three phase system, any two "hot" wires are not opposites (when one is at maximum, the other is somewhere in between max and min, or 120 degrees apart), much like clock hands that are at 12, 4 and 8.  The distance to the center is the same, but the sweep across the face is shorter in the latter case.

@JimStewart I don't think it is OP has changed the facts but rather, based on the answer OP changed their assumptions about what he had and now realizes they are tapped into a 3-phase service that they didn't even know was a possibility before.

manassehkatz the OP wrote in the question that he was on single phase. In formulating your answer you perhaps realized that this could not be true, but I did not. I was wracking what's left of my 80-year-old brain how he could get 217 V rather than 250 V.  I feel I have been the victim of elder abuse. Finally in a comment after your answer he says he now realizes he is on 3-phase.

I suspect what threw you off is that the standard - look on any large appliance - is 208V/240V. So it takes a bit of a jump to realize that 240V -> 250V also means 208V -> 217V.

Referring to 240V as two phases isn't necessarily incorrect – it just happens that two phase is technically the same as (and indistinguishable from) center-tapped single phase if you ignore which leg/tap is grounded.

@ntoskrnl True. 0° and 180° are two phases. 180° can also be thought of a "0°, but inverted", but that doesn't change the fact that it's also 180°. (And if you're ignoring ground potential, bridging two of three phases looks just as "single phase" as split-phase does.) Though as "two-phase" can also refer to historic 0°+90° systems, avoiding it is probably best. However "single-phase" is also misleading (for the love of OSHA, don't ignore ground!) Why can you get power when you bridge the two hots? Because they're out of phase.

You don't have a single-phase (or split-phase) feed, as you thought. Your service is actually two phases out of a three-phase feed, which is fairly rare but found in a few places including New York City apartments and various commercial buildings.
Years ago, service voltages were set at 120V/240V nominal (after many steps of upgrades from 100V at the dawn of electric service) for split phase and 120V/208V for three-phase. Utilities have been slowly increasing their delivered voltage towards 125V/250V (to be able to deliver more power on existing service wires) for split phase. The resulting phase-to-phase voltage in a three-phase system with 125V phase-to-neutral, is 217V (125V times √3).
This is normal and within spec. There is no fault.

Posting this as a concise (less than half as many words) alternative to the other answer.

"Utilities have been slowly increasing their delivered voltage towards 125V/250V (to be able to deliver more power on existing service wires) for split phase." -- Do you have any references where I could read more about this?
